# Passing a value to onTerminate with AnonymousThread

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-xe2

I have a running threading application that is computing some longer calculations.

```
procedure TForm.calculationInThread(value: Integer);
var aThread : TThread;
begin
  aThread :=
    TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
      procedure
      begin
        myCalculation(value);           
      end
    );
  aThread.FreeOnTerminate := True;
  aThread.OnTerminate := self.calculationInThreadEnd;
  aThread.Start;
end;
```

And an implementation of calculationInThreadEnd;

```
procedure TForm.calculationInThreadEnd(Sender: TObject);
begin
   doSomething;
end;
```

I may miss just something stupid, but how to pass a value to calculationInThreadEnd? I found

```
TThread.SetReturnValue(value);
```

but how do i access that in the onTerminate call?

**Solution**

```
type THackThread = class(TThread);

procedure TForm1.calculationInThreadEnd(Sender: TObject);
var Value: Integer;
begin
    Value := THackThread(Sender as TThread).ReturnValue;  
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Sender` parameter of the `OnTerminate` event is the thread object. So you can do this:

```
aThread :=
  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    begin
      myCalculation(value);           
      TThread.SetReturnValue(...);
    end
  );
```

Then in the `OnTerminate` event handler you can do:

```
procedure TForm.calculationInThreadEnd(Sender: TObject);
var
  Value: Integer;
begin
  Value := (Sender as TThread).ReturnValue;
end;
```

**Update**

The return value property is protected so you'll need to use the protected hack to gain access to it.

Comment: I cant access it like that, it fails with the error

[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(33): E2362 Cannot access protected symbol TThread.ReturnValue

and TThread does not contain a member named 'ReturnValue'

Comment: Use the protected hack then. However, all this struggling suggests that this entire approach is not the best way to go.

Comment: CreateAnonymousThread is returning TThread, so even if I try to use proteceted hack, it compiles but crashes with invalid class typecast. I like the AnonymousThread for its simplity, I dont need to access the running thread once its started, all I would like to know is, which Thread ended when calling calculationInThreadEnd. Ofc I could make a list (fifo or something similar), add the thread identifier there and process it in the calculationInThreadEnd function. But I thought there would be a more elegant and clean solution.

Comment: Works fine here with the protected hack.

Comment: You were right, I missed another cast to the hack. For anything more complex I guess i will go with a different approach, in this case for simplicity I will go with the hack.